# Kubernetes's LoadBalancer yaml not working even though CLI `expose` function works

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

This is my `Service` and `Deployment` yaml that I am running on `minikube`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: node-hello-world
  labels:
    app: node-hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: node-hello-world
        image: node-hello-world:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node-hello-world-load-balancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30002
  selector:
    name: node-hello-world
```

Results:

```
$ minikube service node-hello-world-load-balancer --url
http://192.168.99.101:30002
$ curl http://192.168.99.101:30002
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.101 port 30002: Connection refused
```

However, running the following CLI worked:

```
$ kubectl expose deployment node-hello-world --type=LoadBalancer
$ minikube service node-hello-world --url
http://192.168.99.101:30130
$ curl http://192.168.99.101:30130
Hello World!
```

What am I doing wrong with my LoadBalancer yaml config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have configured wrong the service selector

```
selector:
name: node-hello-world
```

it should be:

```
selector:
app: node-hello-world
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/

you can debug this by describing the service, and seeing that the endpoint list is empty, so there are no pods mapped to your endpoint's service list

```
kubectl describe svc node-hello-world-load-balancer | grep -i endpoints
Endpoints:                <none>
```

Comment: the service selector should match the deployment selector. in your case, for deployment you have named your selector "app",and the service selector is "app"